# Procedurally Generated Heart In JavaScript

Tags: javascript, math

slowly learning JavaScript on the side and wanted to try and animate this with Three.JS:
https://www.reddit.com/r/gifs/comments/ag6or3/send_this_to_your_loved_ones_for_valentines/

I was trying to re-create that equation but ran into a wall in that the code below is not producing the right result. I had read that JS has some big issues with floating point numbers and in particular cubed roots don't really work all that well.

```
for (var x = -100; x < 100; x++)
{
 y = Math.pow(x, 2/3) + 0.9 * (Math.pow(3.0 - (x*x), 0.5)) * Math.sin(10 * 
 Math.PI * x)
}
```

Does that look right to you JS masters?

Here is my code implementation in trying to get this to work including the fix mentioned below.
https://codesandbox.io/s/vjm4xox185

Comment: What do you mean it's not producing the right result? What result are you getting? Please create a minimal, complete, and verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Added a link above to a codesandbox project.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the range of the graph you linked to. The heart is being drawn in the range of `x: [-2, 2]` , but your loop is from `x: [-100, 100]`. This means you'll probably get undefined results for all x values except `-1, 0, 1`. Try narrowing down the range of your `for()` loop, and you should get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the result of the calculation of `(Math.pow(3.0 - (x*x), 0.5))` return `NAN` as if not realistic number

Read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow) for more information about `Math.pow(negativeNumber, 0.5)`
so i added `validPow` that will validate the x is positive or negative and return the right result.

```js
for (var x = -100; x < 100; x++)
{

 y = (Math.pow(x, 2/3) + 0.9) * (validPow(3.0 - (x*x), 0.5)) * 
 Math.sin(10 * Math.PI * x)
 
 console.log(y)
 

}

function validPow(x, y)
{
            var result = Math.pow(x, y);
            if (x > 0)
            {
                return result;
            }
            else
            {
                return -1 * Math.pow(-x, y);
            }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried implementing this in my code sandbox but the results seemed off. I added a link in my original post.

Comment: The values seems right, there is negative and positive numbers in position array and it still write a straight line. Im not really good with `g_Geometry` library your are using. but something is off it should at least not write a straight line

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved this.

It came down to this line with the key being to use Math.abs(x) inside the first Math.pow statement:
`var y = Math.pow(Math.abs(x), 0.66) + (0.9 * Math.sqrt(3.3 - x * x)) * Math.sin(10 * Math.PI * x);`

Thanks for everyone who provided input and help!

You can view the final result here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/vjm4xox185